# SailsJS Waterline Adapter Without Alter or Create (for Production)

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

How do I run the SailsJS Waterline adapter without alter or create.  My database does not give alter or create permissions to production app user.  So, I need to run it without but when I start SailsJS it complains it doesn't have permission.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Waterline adapters are great on keep the Models transparent from database structure.  But on a SQL database like SQL the SailsJS runs some auto migration that adds temporary columns.  To avoid this you just need to add `migrate: 'safe'` to each of your models.  This really should be the default for production but it isn't yet.

example:

```
    module.exports = {
       migrate: 'safe',
       adapters: 'mysql',
       attributes: {
           column1: 'string',
           column2: 'integer'
       }
    };
```